# How do instruction sets differentiate value from reference

Tags: c++, memory, assembly

Let's look at this code:

```
int main ()
{
    int a = 5;
    int&b = a;

    cout << a << endl;  // 5 is displayed
    cout << b << endl;  // 5 is also displayed

    return 0;
}
```

This is the behavior I saw in my debugger.

`int a = 5` will assign value `5` in memory address -0x14(%rbp)

`int& b = a` will assign value `-0x14(%rbp)` in memory address -0x8(%rbp)

When I do `cout << a << endl` the value in the address of a (i.e. -0x14(%rbp)) will be displayed.

But somehow when I do `cout << b << endl` the value in the address of b (i.e. `-0x8(%rbp)`) is determined to be an address then the value of that address (`-0x14(%rbp)`) is displayed.

This is the assembly for the std::cout calls:

```
20                  cout << a << endl;
0000000000401506:   mov -0xc(%rbp),%eax
0000000000401509:   mov %eax,%edx
000000000040150b:   lea 0x6f8c9c6e(%rip),%rcx        # 0x6fccb180 <libstdc++-6!_ZSt4cout>
0000000000401512:   callq 0x4015f8 <_ZNSolsEi>
0000000000401517:   lea 0xe2(%rip),%rdx        # 0x401600 <_ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_>
000000000040151e:   mov %rax,%rcx
0000000000401521:   callq 0x401608 <_ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E>
21                  cout << b << endl;
0000000000401526:   mov -0x8(%rbp),%rax
000000000040152a:   mov (%rax),%eax
000000000040152c:   mov %eax,%edx
000000000040152e:   lea 0x6f8c9c4b(%rip),%rcx        # 0x6fccb180 <libstdc++-6!_ZSt4cout>
0000000000401535:   callq 0x4015f8 <_ZNSolsEi>
000000000040153a:   lea 0xbf(%rip),%rdx        # 0x401600 <_ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_>
0000000000401541:   mov %rax,%rcx
0000000000401544:   callq 0x401608 <_ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E>
24                  return 0;
```

Question:

Both std::cout instructions are very similar, How is `a` treated differently from `b`?

Comment: This is not something the CPU does or understands. This is the rules of the language. Your compiler tells the CPU to dereference that reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: it does not.

CPU itself doesn't care about which type is stored where, it just executes instructions generated by compiler.

Compiler knows that `b` is a reference, not an `int`. So it instructs CPU to treat `b` as a pointer.

If you look at the assembly code for your program, you'll see that the instructions for accessing `a` and `b` are different: the part for `b` contains an extra instruction

```
mov (%rax),%eax
```

which is the dereferencing step. (In this assembly notation, parentheses mean dereferencing, so this instruction means something like eax = *rax).

Comment: I have undated my question to be more clear, I don't see a difference in the instruction set used to get the value of a and the value that b refers to

Comment: I do. For `cout << b`, there is `000000000040152a:   mov (%rax),%eax` for `cout << b` which is exactly dereferencing the pointer. There is no such instruction for `cout << a`)

Comment: Ah wait, why does this instruction dereference? is it the parenthesis?!?

Comment: Exactly. `(%rax)` means 'memory at the address which is stored in `rax`'.

Comment: ahhh I did not know this..Thank you! Please update your answer so I accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

I presume you've requested absolutely no optimization.  Although even
then, I would have expected accessing `a` and accessing `b` to generate
exactly the same code (in this case, at least).

With regards to how the compiler knows: `a` and `b` have different
types, so the compiler knows to do different things with them.  The
standard has been designed so that replacing `int&` with `int* const`,
and then automatically dereferencing on each access (except the
initialization) will result in a conforming implementation; it looks
like this is what your compiler is doing.

Comment: Isnt't `int const*` a pointer to a constant integer ? Don't you mean `int * const` ?